# Google Drive API to list folders in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a bunch of folders in my personal Google Drive, each starting with "Renamed". I want to list these. I used the snippet [in the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) but it doesn't print anything:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account 

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            service_account_path,
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
)
service = build(api_name='drive', api_version='v3', credentials=credentials)

page_token = None
while True:
    response = service.files().list(q="(name contains \"Renamed\") and (mimeType=\"application/vnd.google-apps.folder\")",
                                        spaces='drive',
                                        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                        pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

I then included some additional parameters in the call; again no folders are found:

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = service.files().list(q="(name contains \"Renamed\") and (mimeType=\"application/vnd.google-apps.folder\")",
                                        spaces='drive',
                                        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                        corpora='allDrives',
                                        includeItemsFromAllDrives='true',
                                        supportsAllDrives='true',
                                        pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

When dropping the `mimeType` part from the  `q` parameter and keeping only: `q="name contains \"Renamed\""`, it still didn't print any of the folders. But when I modified it to `q="name contains \"Central\""`, it successfully found a spreadsheet called "Central Sheet". It seems I am doing something wrong when listing **folders** but I can successfully retrieve files. What am I missing?

**Note:** I tried running the query also [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22name%20contains%20%5C%22Renamed%5C%22%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22files%2CincompleteSearch%2Ckind%2CnextPageToken%22%7D) and it returned the folders in question correctly. I then updated the `fields` and `q` parameters accordingly to: `q="name contains \"Renamed\""` and `fields="files,incompleteSearch,kind,nextPageToken"`. Still no folders are retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite odd. I have copy/paste the code snippets shared and after having created several folders in my account with names that include *'Renamed'* I am able to successfully get the entire folder list.

As seen below first snippet and result below:

[image]

And below the second snippet with its result:

[image]

Should you need to take a look at my code see it below:

```html
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account 

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'API KEY' #Your API KEY goes here
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_creds = credentials.with_subject('yourPersonalAccount@gmail.com')

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=delegated_creds)

""" page_token = None
while True:
    response = service.files().list(q="(name contains \"Renamed\") and (mimeType=\"application/vnd.google-apps.folder\")",
                                        spaces='drive',
                                        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                        pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break  """

page_token = None
while True:
    response = service.files().list(q="(name contains \"Renamed\") and (mimeType=\"application/vnd.google-apps.folder\")",
                                        spaces='drive',
                                        fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                        corpora='allDrives',
                                        includeItemsFromAllDrives='true',
                                        supportsAllDrives='true',
                                        pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        print('Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id')))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

You can remove comments as needed. So this might be something local in your environment. Something I noticed is that you are using a service account but no impersonation has been declared, you may want to double check that on your end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I added the `delegated_creds = credentials.with_subject(<EMAIL>)` part and now I'm getting the following error message: `Client is unathorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.`

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by this as it is an app on my own device with my personal email address. The service account was also set up from the same personal email address.

Comment: Alright, what type of keys are you using? A JSON key or an API Key? Since you are using a Gmail.com account you should be using and API Key and be stored here _SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'API KEY'_ (my bad, I am using a Google Workspace account which actually needs a JSON Key but yours does not)